# internet explorer ignores some directives when they appear on web pages on a certain server

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have 2 web pages, gantt and securityTV. Gantt is complicated, but here's security tv:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://ctadweb/B5Tours/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%; display:table;">
        <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">
            <h1 style="color:green; font-size:60px;">RAYTHEON ACCESS</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="site-footer" style="margin-top:-132px;">
        <div>
            <img src="http://ctadweb/B5Tours/Content/FooterPicture.jpg"/>
            <div id="site-footer-image-background" style="margin-top:-4px;"></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and the relevant part of site.css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 128px; 
}
.site-footer div{
    width:100%; 
    text-align:center; 
    height:128px;
}
#site-footer-image-background{
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
    background-color:#365f93;
    height:67px;
    top:-67px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Now here's the weirdness. When I save that web page and open it with internet explorer, it runs fine. When I run my C# project which creates that web page, so we're looking at localhost:/securityTV, it runs fine. But when I publish the project and try to run off ctadweb, it doesn't cooperate. The Raytheon access text isn't vertically centered, it's aligned to the top of the screen.

additionally, in my gantt page, I rotate some headers sideways, but just like with `vertical-align: middle;` it only works when I'm testing it, when I open a saved version of the page, or when I use firefox. I tried opening internet explorer's options and disabling some addons, but all I have under "currently loaded addons" are 5 which are disabled, something called "research" which is not available, and "Java(tm) Plug-In 2 SSV Helper". I tried disabling them both, but I got the same problem. I've tried 2 computers pointing to ctadweb, both get the same (wrong) display.

Comment: from IE the File>Properties menu will tell you which IE security zone a domain is running in.....f12>Emulation tab, will tell you which Emulation mode is being used by that web page (not local file) and how it was established. Your company should be using Enterprise Mode lists to manage emulation modes for legacy intranet sites, it can over-ride settings for "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View".

Comment: both on the problem server and on the localhost, I have the same thing for zone: "Local intranet | Protected Mode: Off". Would I be able to see the difference from the properties view?